# Object doesn't support property or method 'create' on IE11 when run as a webapp, fine when straight opening HTML in browser

Tags: javascript, web-applications, internet-explorer-11, sigma.js

I'm trying to get a working prototype of [sigma.js](http://sigmajs.org/) working.

I can download their package, and straight up open the example files in my browser (IE11), and it works fine.

However, if I try deploy it to a webapp, it gives me this error:

```
var _handlers = Object.create(null);
```

> Object doesn't support property or method 'create'

The HTML source is exactly the same, except that the script imports look like:

```
<script src="js/sigma/src/misc/sigma.misc.drawHovers.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script src="../src/misc/sigma.misc.drawHovers.js"></script>
```

Other notes:

This webapp **does** work on FF11, and **doesn't** work on IE8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that you aren't in compatibility mode.

Click the cog in top right corner -> compatibility view settings -> either remove the website from the list, or uncheck 'display intranet sites in Compatibility View'.